# how to distinguish AAA:BBB and AAA:BBB:CCC using regular expression?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Say there is string

A:B:C **A:B C:B** C:D:E C:D:E:F

I want to replace all substring which match the pattern "X:Y" to "X:0:Y", in this example , it should be:

A:B:C **A:0:B C:0:B** C:D:E C:D:E:F

Is it possible to do it using one regex replacement?

Comment: Regex replace nothing itself, for this give more infos : language, platform...

Comment: Thanks,I am using boost::regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
(^|\s)(.):(.)(?=\s|$)
```

with

```
\1\2:0:\3
```

`^|\s` - start of line of white-space
`.` - wild-card
`:` - colon
`.` - wild-card
`\s|$` - white-space or end of line
`?=` is look-ahead, otherwise `A:B C:D` won't both match.

`\1` - the matching string for the first thing you put in brackets - `(^|\s)`
`\2` - the matching string for the second thing you put in brackets - 1st `(.)`
`\3` - the matching string for the third thing you put in brackets - 2nd `(.)`

A common alternative for `\1`, etc. is `$1`, etc.

You can also use `\w` (word character) instead of `.` for your example.

**EDIT:**

From the title of the question, it looks like you may want to match one or more (`+`) word characters:

```
(^|\s)(\w+):(\w+)(?=\s|$)
```

**EDIT 2:** Fixed regex to use look-ahead.

[Boost test](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2xLEch%243).